# How to color groups of a big number in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, numbers, latex

I want to color the individual groups of a big number differently. For example

```
111222333444.555
```

I want 111 to be red, 222 to be green, 333 to be blue, and 444.555 to be black.

Until now, I used this:

```
\newcommand{    \byte}[1]{{\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\kilobyte}[1]{{\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.5}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\megabyte}[1]{{\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.0,1.0}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\gigabyte}[1]{{\textcolor[rgb]{0.7,0.0,0.0}{#1}}}

\newcommand{\BBx}[1]{{\byte{#1}}}
\newcommand{\KBx}[2]{{\kilobyte{#1},\BBx{#2}}}
\newcommand{\MBx}[3]{{\megabyte{#1},\KBx{#2}{#3}}}
\def\BBrelax#1\relax{\BBx{#1}}
\def\KBrelax#1,#2\relax{\KBx{#1}{#2}}
\def\MBrelax#1,#2,#3\relax{\MBx{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\BB#1{\BBrelax#1\relax}
\def\KB#1{\KBrelax#1\relax}
\def\MB#1{\MBrelax#1\relax}
```

and I would write

```
\MB{111,222,333.444} blah blah blah \KB{111,222}
```

But this has the disadvantage that I myself have to determine how big the number is and use the correct command depending on the number of digits and I had to separate them with a , by hand.
However, now i load this data automatically (csvreader) so I need a command to do all that automatically.

Basically I search a command implementation where i can say

```
\mynumber{111222333444.666, red, green, blue, black}
\mynumber{111222.333, red, green, blue, black}
```

and it does the right thing for me (The last 3 digits including the decimals would be black, the thousands blue, the millions green, and the billions red) It would be ok to have a upper bound (for example to handle a maximum number of groups) but it must be able to handle big numbers as well as small numbers.

What I have tried: I tried using the \num and \sepnum command, both seem to be unable to do what i want. I tried implementing it myself with the fp and some clever calculations, but for that I would need floating point modulo and integer division, both are not supported by that package.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I want to use it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple} % for csv reader
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\myno{.555}
\myno{111222333444.555}
\myno{111222333444}
\myno{444555666777888999.12345}

\begin{figure}[htp!]
\centering
\csvreader[tabular=r r, table head=Hello & World\\]{test.csv}{Foo=\foo,Bar=\bar}{\myno{\foo} & \myno{\bar}}
\caption{Baz}
\label{figure:baz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

with the csv file (test.csv):

```
Foo,Bar
1,2
222,333
222333.444,11122233344555
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find a sample TeX file with macros for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

%111222333444.555
%I want 
%111 to be red, 
%222 to be green, 
%333 to be blue, and 
%444.555 to be black.

\makeatletter
% Two counters, one for each command and another for each digits.
\newcounter{myno}
\newcounter{mynod}

% Its nothing, but just to have \@nil command to parse the string.
\let\@nil\relax
% \myno will take the number and add .@@ after the number so that
% even if you have given a number without decimal it won't fail
\def\myno#1{%
 \expandafter\myNo#1.@@\@nil%
}
% Storing the default value if there is no decimal value
\def\parse@@{@@}
% Defining \myNo which contains either 000.00 or 000.@@ as argument
\expandafter\def\expandafter\myNo#1.#2\@nil{\def\myNo@two{#2}%
 % the counter of command is incremented
 \stepcounter{myno}%
 % the counter of digit is reset to 0
 \setcounter{mynod}{0}%
 % iterating through each digits and storing it in a control sequence
 % also note that here #1 will be digits before decimal
 \@tfor\xx:=#1\do{\stepcounter{mynod}%
   \expandafter\xdef\csname myno@\themyno @\themynod\endcsname{\xx}%
 }%
 % setting the total digits defined to a temp counter a and setting another temp counter b to 0
 \@tempcnta=\themynod%
 \@tempcntb=0%
 % make a loop if tempcnta>0
 \loop\ifnum\@tempcnta>0%
   \advance\@tempcntb by 1%
   \xdef\myCtr{\the\@tempcnta}%
   \xdef\myCtrb{\the\@tempcntb}%
   % setting the right colour at right position
   \textcolor{%
     \ifnum\myCtr<4 black\else%
     \ifnum\myCtr<7 blue\else%
     \ifnum\myCtr<10 green\else%
     \ifnum\myCtr<13 red\else%
     cyan\fi\fi\fi\fi%
     % putting the digit which was already stored
   }{\csname myno@\themyno @\myCtrb\endcsname}%
   \advance\@tempcnta by -1%
 \repeat%
  % if #2=@@ then there is no decimal stuff otherwise just strip .@@ which was already added in main macro
   \ifx\myNo@two\parse@@\def\decimal{}\else%
     \expandafter\myDec#2\@nil%
   \fi%
   % print decimal in black colour
   \textcolor{black}{\decimal}%
}
% strip .@@ if it is there
\def\myDec#1.#2\@nil{\def\decimal{.#1}}

\makeatother

\myno{.555}

\myno{111222333444.555}

\myno{111222333444}

\myno{444555666777888999.12345}

\end{document}
```

Comment: upvote because it works. If you could explain to me how (in a comment or an edit) I will mark it as accepted also.

Comment: another issue: although it works in plain text, as i described, i am using it in a csv reader. in there, all numbers remain black. any ideas why?

Comment: Please post a MWE.

Comment: @loonytune: added step-by-step procedure. Hope this helps.

Comment: I added my use case as edit to the question, just copy your solution in it and you can see it. in normal text it works, in the table it doesnt.

Comment: Oh! That token is not expandable. Sorry.

Comment: Does that mean that your solution will not work in a csvreader?

Comment: Yes. Because the value is taken as single token and it act as single  command and it is not breakable into individual digits.